# What is the side effect of not implementing getType(Uri uri) in ContentProvider for Android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I've always implemented the getType() method for my items but recently quesstion as to when it's even used.  When I put a breakpoint into getType(), it is never called.

I was wondering if I can just neglect this method, and what the repercussions of doing so might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be called if Android needs to find the MIME type for your `Uri`. This will be whenever somebody calls `getType()` on a `ContentResolver` for one of your `Uri` values.

If your `ContentProvider` is purely for internal use within your app, you are welcome to experiment with a no-op implementation. If, however, your `ContentProvider` will be used by third parties, since you have no control over if/when they call `getType()` on a `ContentResolver`, you should have a real implementation.